# Uncaught TypeError: s is not a constructor

Tags: яндекс-карта-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код данный форум не дает вставить - глючит и виснет, так что прикрепляю не очень читабельный код.
Просто не отображает карту, какие то новые ошибки вылезли сегодня... Вчера на простом вызове вместе с загрузкой сайта положила карта хостинг - бесконечно создавала карты. А вызов был простой, с примера яндекс карт.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Упорно не понимаю, что не так с форумом, но скрипт упорно не дает вставить...
Ссылка на код сайта
view-source:https://vetspb.ru/